# get the value that is inside an array of objects which is a value inside another object

Tags: javascript, object

If i have something like this

```
var response =[{2017-03-17:[{command:"00",date_time:"2017-03-17",device_id:"ITPL",e1:"2.30",e2:"3.30",e3:"4.40",voltage:"270"},{command:"00",date_time:"2017-03-17",device_id:"ITPL",e1:"2.30",e2:"3.30",e3:"4.40",voltage:"290"}]},
               {2017-04-17:[{command:"00",date_time:"2017-04-22",device_id:"ITPL",e1:"2.30",e2:"3.30",e3:"4.40",voltage:"240"},{command:"00"date_time:"2017-04-22",device_id:"ITPL",e1:"2.30",e2:"3.30",e3:"4.40",voltage:"250"}]}]
```

I want something this to be converted to something like this

```
[{x:2017-03-17, y:270},{x:2017-03-17, y:290},{x:2017-04-22, y:240},{x:2017-04-22,y:250}]
```

This is what I tried but it shows an error

```
    var tArray = [];
response.forEach(a=>{
    let newObj = {x:a.date_time,y:a.voltage}
    tArray.push(newObj);
})
```

Comment: you are missing commas in the objects in your response array

Comment: your object is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the inner values form the array and take the key from the outer object for a new result array.

```js
var response = [{ "2017-03-17": [{ command: "00", date_time: "2017-03-17", device_id: "ITPL", e1: "2.30", e2: "3.30", e3: "4.40", voltage: "270" }, { command: "00", date_time: "2017-03-17", device_id: "ITPL", e1: "2.30", e2: "3.30", e3: "4.40", voltage: "290" }] }, { "2017-04-17": [{ command: "00", date_time: "2017-04-22", device_id: "ITPL", e1: "2.30", e2: "3.30", e3: "4.40", voltage: "240" }, { command: "00", date_time: "2017-04-22", device_id: "ITPL", e1: "2.30", e2: "3.30", e3: "4.40", voltage: "250" }] }],
    result = response.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
        return r.concat(o[key].map(function (p) {
            return { x: key, y: p.voltage };
        }));
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped